# Is there a way to specify a Layout to use for a ListView when the adapter is empty?

Tags: android, layout

I have a complex empty view in a layout, with an icon, text, button, etc.

It is easy to select a view within my layout.xml to use when the listview is empty, similar to
**getListView().setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));**
This code sets the empty view works just fine when it resides in the layout.xml file.

Now I want to refactor this view into its own empty.xml layout file, and have coded it similar to the following:

```
// Setup the empty layout.xml
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View vlEmpty = vi.inflate(R.layout.empty, null);

// Find the empty layout view
vEmpty = vlEmpty.findViewById(R.id.llEmpty);
vEmpty.setOnClickListener(ocl);

// Find the ListView
vListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvWords);
vListView.setEmptyView(vEmpty);
```

The problem is that the details within llEmpty never show up;  The exact same layout and view works withing the main layout, just not refactored into its own xml file.

Has anyone got something like this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that `setEmptyView()` automatically makes the supplied `View` a child of any container in your activity.

Personally, I'd just use the `<include>` element rather than inflating it separately. But, if you really want to inflate it separately, the answer that Femi posted while I was writing this may work, depending on what the `ListView`'s parent is.

Comment: This actually solved my problem, where Femi's answer is real interesting, and works in part, it will take a little more work to get working.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to pass the proper context to the inflater:

```
vListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvWords);
View vlEmpty = vi.inflate(R.layout.empty, (ViewGroup)vListView.getParent());
```

which (should) make them both live in the same root view. It may be sufficient to just pass the root view of the parent activity.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: This works in that it now show up, but at the bottom of the layout.  There is actually another view after the list view -- I'll investigate a little further

Comment: Yeah, if you inflate it it doesn't come with any of the layout attributes so you need to manually set the height/width/margins/etc. If your root view is (for example) a RelativeLayout you'll need to use the appropriate settings. As an example: `TextView vlEmpty = vi.inflate(R.layout.empty, (ViewGroup)vListView.getParent()); vlEmpty.setId(1); lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM); lp.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0); addView(vlEmpty, lp);` and then set empty view.

Comment: +1 for a real interesting answer; I would have accepted it, but didn't have time to test fully; I'm almost tempted to add another question just to have you answer it.